# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Tags: php, macos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

PhpMyAdmin error on MacOS. I want answer I really have no idea what I need to do to resolve this.

Comment: can you give some  more information?

Comment: Check if your MySQL Server is running: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50227592/4684797

Answer (score 149):

change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

The reason for this is that pma tries to connect to the mysql.socket if you use localhost. If you use 127.0.0.1 PMA makes a TCP connection which should work.

Comment: I was glad to find this answer to get things working, but what's the real fix? This is a workaround. You *should* be able to use `localhost`.

Comment: You'd think so, but apparently not. Regarding the "connection type" setting: "Deprecated since version 4.7.0: This setting is no longer used as of 4.7.0, since MySQL decides the connection type based on host, so it could lead to unexpected results."  Ref: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

Comment: The "real fix" is to read and understand the MySQL documentation, then edit your configuration files and have a system, where you know what's going on, instead of just following some advice and forget everything as soon as it's working. If you want to use `localhost` you have to configure MySQL to listen on  a socket instead of TCP/IP. I would always recommend that, when your Database is on the same machine.

Comment: thanks a lot man. I was stuck with this for a while. Didn't know the problem is so small.

Comment: What do I do if my MySQL server is hosted on a different IP, such as "64.233.191.255"? I have my MySQL bind=64.233.191.255 , in my config-db.php file, I have: $dbserver='64.233.191.255';  (I tried your solution anyways, still getting the error). I'm trying to get phpmyadmin 4:4.9.5+dfsg1-2 working on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 31):

[This](https://garbagevalue.com/blog/mysqli-real-connect-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-phpmyadmin) worked for me.

Locate `config.sample.inc.php`

Change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

into

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Save.

Then rename the file and remove **sample** from the name.

Comment: thanks for pointing out to make sure to remove sample from the name where ever it could be written.

Answer (score 28):

## Maybe your SQL server has been stopped.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

or

```
sudo service mysqld start # older versions
sudo service mysql start # latest versions
```

And use `service mysql status` to check the status.

---

To keep running MySQL.

Use:

```
sudo systemctl enable MySQL # older versions
sudo systemctl start mysql.service # latest versions
```

Comment: service mysqld restart

Comment: It worked for me but the big question is why it stopped? Cause i'm getting this very often.

Comment: @Komi use `sudo systemctl enable mysql` to keep running MySQL. sorry for the late reply. I missed this completely.

Answer (score 23):

I'm trying this before

```
cd /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

Then

```
gedit config.inc.php
```

Find this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] =
```

If there is `localhost` change it to `127.0.0.1`

> Note : if there is '//' remove // before `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']`

I checked again `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

Mysqli said:

> "phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
> rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
> password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
> the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

I'm opening again `config.inc.php` and I found

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] =
```

Fill the password with your password

It worked for me. It may work for you too.

Comment: save me a lot of time

Comment: As of Oct 2018 , MAMP Path should be **/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php**. It worked like charm :-)

Answer (score 11):

## mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

#### Background:

I was just wanted to run some PHPUnit tests on my Mac, using Terminal.
Some of the classes I wanna test was having to connect MySQL DB which was created and managed by PHPMyAdmin, and the web app I was working was working fine in the localhost. So when I ran that testcases I got the following error on my terminal:

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

#### Solution:

So with the itchiness I had to resolve it and run my test I searched in few SO Q&A threads and tried out. And a combination of changes worked for me.

1. Locate your `config.inc.php` file which relates to PHPMyAdmin.
2. Locate the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` mostly this line might have been commented out by default, if so please uncomment it.
3. And replace that line with following:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`

4. Save it and restart the MySQL Database from your XAMPP control panel (manager-osx).
5. Change your `$host` parameter value in the `mysqli_connect()` method to following:

`$_connection = mysqli_connect(**"localhost: 3306"**, $_mysql_username, $_mysql_password, $_database);`

**Note:** This `3306` is my MySQL port number which is its default. You should better check what's your actual MySQL Port number before going to follow these steps.

And that's all. For me only these set of steps worked and nothing else. I ran my Unit Tests and it's working fine and the DB data were also updated properly according to the tests.

#### Why this works:

The closest reason I could have found is that it works because sometimes the `mysqli_connect` method requires a working socket(IP Address of the DB Host along with the Port number) of the database. So if you have commented out the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';` line or have set 'localhost' as the value in it, it ignores the port number. But if you wanna use a socket, then you have to use '127.0.0.1' or the real hostname. (for me it appears to be regardless of the default port number we really have, we have to do the above steps.) Read the following [link of PHPMyAdmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html) for further details.

Hope this might be helpful to somebody else out there.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

I fixed the issue today using the steps below:

1. If config.inc.php does not exists in phpMyadmin directory Copy config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php.
2. Add socket to `/* Server parameters */`

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';
   ```
3. Save the file and access phpmyadmin through url.

If you are using the mysql 8.0.12 you should use legacy password encryption as the strong encryption is not supported by the php client.
[image]

Comment: Definitely the best answer for macOS users!

Comment: While using php and httpd installed from HOMEBREW i had to use the legacy Password encryption to make it work before that using native PHP and httpd from Macos Catalina i had no need to change it, so when i reinstalled PHP and HTTPD from homebrew i lost connection... Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5):

First of all, make sure the mysql service is running:

```
ps elf|grep mysql
```

you will see an output like this if is running:

```
4 S root      9642     1  0  80   0 -  2859 do_wai 23:08 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/tomcat-machine.local.pid
4 S mysql     9716  9642  0  80   0 - 200986 poll_s 23:08 pts/0   00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/tomcat-machine.local.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/tomcat-machine.local.pid
```

then change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

The default password for "root" user is empty "" do not type anything for the password

If it does not allow empty password you need to edit config.inc.php again and change:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

The problem is a combination of config settings and MySQL not running. This was what helped me to fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

Try just

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

It worked for me

Comment: does it delete mysql data ? or just it will start only ?

Comment: Hello, Just restart the server

Answer (score 1):

If you are using archlinux or Ubuntu just type the commands below:

```
cd /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

then

```
sudo gedit config.inc.php
```

Then when you access the file look for the scripts below,

```
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] ='localhost'
```

remove '//' so that it remains as shown below:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] ='localhost'
```

Then change the '**localhost**' to '**127.0.0.1**' and the script should turn as shown below:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] ='127.0.0.1'
```

Get back to your browser and type http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/

If it is still refusing

You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

so then get back to the same file **config.inc.php** you were editing and do as follows:

```
cd /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

then

```
sudo gedit config.inc.php
```

search for the script below

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] =''
```

Fill the password with your root password

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] ='your_password'
```

And it should work.

Comment: -bash: cd: /opt/lamp/phpmyadmin: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem on **CentOS**.

First I try this

```sh
sudo service mysql restart
```

Then error shows up

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart mysql.service
Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit not found.
```

Then I Found [this](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17652/failed-to-start-mysqldservice-unit-not-found)

Command this solve my problem

```sh
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Answer (score 0):

If your website was running fine and now unexpected **ERROR**: `(HY000/2002): No such file or directory`

Then you should **NOT CHANGE** any configuration file!

First check server **error.log** file, for Nginx it's located:

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Or for Apache try:

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log
```

In my case I could see **PHP Fatal error: OUT OF MEMORY** in error.log for nginx.

**The solution:** Add more RAM to server.

---

I tried to reboot the web server first before upgrading/adding RAM.
Then I got rid of `ERROR (HY000/2002) but got some ERROR 50X: Connection Error...`

At this point I added 2GB RAM, rebooted the web server and all was working fine!

When the web server was up I noticed 200+ cron-jobs was stuck due to a loop bug in 1 PHP script.

So check which script is consuming memory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` was no path more to `mysqld.sock` defined. So I started a search to find it with: `find / -type s | grep mysqld.sock` but it could not be found.
I reinstalled mysql with: `apt install mysql-server-5.7` (please check before execute the current sql-server-version).

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

I was facing same issue on debian9 VM, I tried to restart MySQL but it didn't solve the issue, after that I increased the RAM (I was reduced) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using SELinux, check this out.

I had the same problem. I was running CentOS 8 with SELinux enforcing, and I was getting the error mentioned in the question (`mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory`) despite having all the configurations fixed correctly. I later got out of trouble after allowing MySQL connections through SELinux.

Check SELinux status using this command:

```sh
sestatus
```

Allow Apache to connect database through SELinux

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Use `-P` option makes the change permanent. Without this option, the boolean would be reset to 0 at reboot.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you used Mac OS and Brew try this:

```
mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using **Ubuntu 22.04** and I found that mysql service is not working.
It works perfectly after running this command

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Hope it helps somewone

Comment: surely it helps but has been proposed several times already, including one of the topmost answers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50227592

Comment: That's right, I didn't noticed it in the answers

Answer (score -2):

In linux just do

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql

sudo systemctl start mysql
```

worked for me

Comment: This answer already there in multiple posts above with +1 > points

Answer (score -3):

If above solutions doesn't work, try to change the default por from 3306, to another one (i.e. 3307)

Comment: This is not about a port for sure

Answer (score -8):

You just need to rename ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 as ib_logfile_0 and ib_logfile_1. Then your problem would be solved.

Comment: That's totally unrelated.

Comment: Your answer in not related to the question. Renaming log files will not help mysqli to find a socket or a connection to the MySQL server. If we misunderstood your answer you might need to update it, otherwise deleting this answer would be better. Please read the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide.