# Wordpress cannot connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have run a mysql server in my macbook, where I can access via both mysql command `mysql -u root` and navicat application. However, when I open the install page of a brand new wordpress app in my macbook. During the installation, I had got：

[image: Image of MySQL error]

Comment: Show us the config (but please remove the password) and the list of the MySQL users.

Comment: It turned out to be I have MySQL version at 8.0.11 that might be unsupported by WordPress (I guess). When I switch the mysql version from 8.0.11 to 5.7.16. It works. Fairly wired though.

Answer (score 30):

MySQL 8.x actually IS supported, but requires a slightly different command when creating the user and password, as version 8 expects passwords to be SHA256 encoded.

When creating the database user, with the MySQL prompt, use the following:

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

So **WITH mysql_native_password** being the main difference. Also, you might want to **use 127.0.0.1** instead of localhost, depending on your settings.

Comment: I have checked and I can confirm it works fabulously beautiful.

Comment: This query works fine but not by copy paste. i guess there is a special character somewhere. please type it.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Thanks, indeed this was the case. I have corrected it.

Comment: This and set the host to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 10):

***Use 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost***

I came across this when installing WordPress locally for plugin development/unit testing and deciding to use the latest of everything! i.e. MySQL 8.0.11, PHP 7.1.16, WordPress 4.9.7.

I was able to connect to the database with [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) desktop client but WordPress would not connect.

[Migrating to MySQL 8.0 for Wordpress – episode 1](https://lefred.be/content/migrating-to-mysql-8-0-for-wordpress-episode-1/) came across a similar problem where I was reminded to add `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to my `wp-config.php`:

Then, the output above was prepended with:

`Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/BrianHenryIE/Sites/wptest/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531`

Line 1531 doesn't really tell much, just the error is sometimes surpressed:

```php
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
} else {
    @mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
}
```

Another SO answer, [mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41997588/336146), told me to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, which I changed in my `wp-config.php`, `define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );`, and everything worked!

Answer (score 4):

It turned out to be I have MySQL version at 8.0.11 that might be unsupported by WordPress (I guess). When I switch the mysql version from 8.0.11 to 5.7.16. It works. Fairly wired though.

Comment: This is simply not true, as you can see in my response.

Answer (score 2):

For my case the issue was MySQL 8.0.18 is setup to run on port 3308 for WAMPserver 3.2.0

Define non standard port in wp-config.php

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3308' );
```

Comment: This worked for me! I was not expecting this to work. Hurrah! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not connect with MySQL root user. Create another user in MySQL to connect in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did that solved my issue was to update to PHP 7.2.x on my IIS Server, then assigned this version to the Wordpress Website in PHPManager (In IIS Manager).

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8 the team changed default value of default_authentication_plugin configuration variable from previous `mysql_native_password` to `caching_sha2_password`.

What this means is that when a client connects to MySQL without specifying which password encryption method it uses MySQL assumes it to be using `caching_sha2_password`. But most of clients currently in use are assuming to use `mysql_native_password`.

To fix this problem, edit your mysql config file. On linux it should be at:

`/etc/my.cnf`

Find and uncomment the following line:

`default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password`

if you can't find it, just add it under `[mysqld]`.

You must restart mysql after this change. On CentOS 7 you can issue this command:

`systemctl restart mysqld`

This permanent solution will fix mysql connection error for all wordpress installations.

Answer (score 0):

For docker mysql  instance

```
docker run --name eight-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too - problem was with the MySQL database.  Changed database to `utf8_general_ci` and connection worked fine