# Cannot connect to the mysql RDS instance on AWS

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a MySQL RDS instance on AWS. I also created an EC2 instance on which I installed Wordpress, Apache, MySQL client, and other dependencies using the script shown below.

-- Script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

yum update -y

yum install httpd php php-mysql -y

cd /var/www/html

echo "healthy" > healthcheck.html

wget https://wordpress.org/wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz

tar -xzf wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz

cp -r wordpress/* /var/www/html/

rm -rf wordpress

rm -rf wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz

chmod -R 755 wp-content

chown -R apache:apache wp-content

chkconfig httpd on

service httpd start
```

I created a database and a master user while creating an RDS instance, and tried to host a Wordpress website. It shows this error every time (**This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at wpsdbserver.cv3al69dy8rq.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com. This could mean your host’s database server is down**).

Both EC2 instance and RDS instance are in the same VPC, and also I have allowed port 3306 from SecurityGroup1(Ec2) to SecurityGroup2(Rds instance). I have entered the correct username, password, and database endpoint. RDS instance has no public access. The rest of the configuration settings are set to default.

Comment: Guess you are using RDS MySQL 8?  Please try with 5.7.

Comment: Are EC2 and RDS in the same subnet, if not , what about ACLs configuration

Comment: @Marcin Yes earlier i was using MySql 8, I now tried the same process with MySql version 5.7.23 and it worked. Can you please explain why this didn't work with Version 8 and worked with Version 5

Comment: @AsriBadlah All the Subnet and ACL settings are set to default. Thanks

Comment: @Marcin, sorry I am new to stack overflow. I'm still finding my way around here

Comment: No problem. Everyone here had to start at one point somehow. Ans thanks for acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by the use of **MySQL 8**. MySQL introduced some changes that causes wordpress not to work out of the box. It has been reported several times before along with potential fixes, e.g. [here](https://www.akamenskiy.com/fix-wordpress-database-connection-mysql-8/), [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-and-mysql-8/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037975/wordpress-cannot-connect-to-mysql-server).

The easiest way to overcome this issue is to use **MySQL 5.7** which works out of the box with Wordpress.