# cannot connect to MySQL server (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I get this error when I try to login in phpmyadmin: "mysqli_real_connect(): no such file or directory"
My os is ubuntu
What should I do?

I even do this
    "change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in config.inc.php"
but it doesn't work

this is the status of MySQL service

```
`sudo service mysql status`
```

> mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en)
>
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-05-19 08:54:24 CST; 2min 4s
>
> Process: 31984 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi
>    Main PID: 1244 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> مه 19 08:54:24 amir systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, sched
>
> مه 19 08:54:24 amir systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart co
>
> مه 19 08:54:24 amir systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
>
> مه 19 08:54:24 amir systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickl
>
> مه 19 08:54:24 amir systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>
> مه 19 08:54:24 amir systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881123/mysqli-real-connect-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: have you tried to access MySQL from terminal? same problem was faced y me as MySQL was not running from root user.

Comment: When I try to access MySQL from terminal, I get this ->
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seen that you changed in **config.inc.php**:

**`localhost` **to** `127.0.0.1`**

Well you could try not doing it by just adding the port-number where the **[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)** runs like in the example below:

**`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3306';`**

Actually, I too had same problem and tried as you did which is ultimately answered everywhere in different forums.

Finally, I tried the above and worked for me. hopefully, it does work for you as well.

Good luck!