# Access Denied - phpMyAdmin - Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: python, flask, phpmyadmin, xampp, flask-sqlalchemy

I restated Xammp server and after restarting, when i try to access phpmyadmin/ , i am still getting Access denied server error in mac os.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlZfC.png)

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881123/mysqli-real-connect-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Usually Xampp (and other pre-packaged kits) install and configure all of the pieces you need. Is this a fresh installation, did it ever work, and have you modified anything after the installation? Are you able to connect correctly through the command line client?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is stopping and restart the server **Xammp**

Comment: After restarting Xammp server , when i am trying to access http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ . i am getting error like mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Opsss. change user to 'admin', it doesn't have privilege to add database. so, change back the user to 'root'. then change the password from the browser.

```
Go to:
```

http://localhost/security/ and then click on the link http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php. after that change password for superuser to 'root'.

After that open your http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

```
Now it works.
```

Comment: How to change the user to admin when i am not even able to open the http://localhost/security/  which is throwing ' site can’t be reached ' error.