# I have problem in wordpress: Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /home/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 1987

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with wordpress on hosting (not lacaly on comouter) database connection error Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /home/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 1987, I checked wp-config, user and database and password everythin is ok....

I done wpconfing check database user and password everything is ok, also, repair of db...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_real\_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881123/mysqli-real-connect-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: It is localy my wordpress is live on server hosting... it is not same situation... a can not doing server chandes licaly

Answer (score 0):

you can change localhost with local address like that

```html
FIND At wp-config.php Line 31-32
/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

replace

```html
/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );
```